# Reference to an explixit construction of a locale from a measurable space

Tags: ct.category-theory, measure-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

In [A sheaf theoretic approach to measure theory](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/students/jackson.pdf) shows that measures on a measurable space are equivalent to measures on some locale whose open sets are the $\sigma$-ideals of the $\sigma$-algebra. The only difference is that the continuity condition for the measures is regularity from below on open sets.

From what I know if I started from a hausdorff topological space, got the Borel measurable space, then the locale would at least contain a discrete copy of the starting topological space since the sets containing just a Singleton are $\sigma$-ideals.

I want to know if someone explicited this construction for some measurable space and use it anywhere, more precisely I would like to know if it obvious that such a locale isn't spatial. I have some trouble computing the $\sigma$-ideals of such a space even in basic examples.

Comment: Have you read this article?
 https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measurable%20locale  (You do get nonspatial locales in this setup, by the way.  In fact, points correspond to atoms in this context, so an atom-free measurable locale has no points.)